# Is there a way to retrieve platform data if a platform device is instantiated through device tree?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver, device-tree

In this [article](https://lwn.net/Articles/448502/), it clearly mentions that platform data through the pointer dev.platform_data can only be retrieved if a driver is instantiated in a 'traditional way' which I presume is through board files. So, if a device tree is used for instantiating the driver this particular pointer will be null and data needs to be retrieved through device tree access functions.

Has this changed since this article was written in 2011?

Comment: A bit. Since 2014 we have a Unified Device property API which allows to retrieve data independently on the resource provider. That's how the modern drivers are written.

Comment: The API is located here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/property.h